# Chloroquinaldol and fresh peppers tasters and non-tasters?

Tags: taste

Chloroquinaldol is an over-the-counter antiseptic drug sold under many names, often in the form of lozenges for mouth infections.

I absolutely hate its taste. The unpleasant sensation is unlike any other bad taste - it feels metallic, "chemical" (like the smell of the storeroom behind the chemistry lab at school) and sends shivers down my spine like bitter taste does - but it is *not* bitter taste.

To most people Chloroqinaldin is just a sweet lozenge, but I have met a few people who describe the same reaction to the drug.

Interestingly, the same people (me included) also describe a similar reaction to fresh bell peppers, equally puzzling to "non-tasters". Thermal processing as well as pickling removes the awful taste, so this specific aversion is distinct from simply not liking bell peppers in any form. In fact I love grilled stuffed peppers my dad makes, and I would probably be emptying jars of pickled peppers while sleepwalking if I sleepwalked ;)

Is this a known phenomenon? Could it be similar to how PTC can be tasted by most but not all people, except here the tasters seem to be a minority?